# Sized question dynamic dispatch Iterator rust

Tags: rust

I'm implementing a struct that holds a reference to a collection of states and able to walk that reference in a cyclic manner.

```
struct Pawn {
    _state: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>>,
}

impl Pawn {

    const ALL_STATES: [u8; 10] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

    fn new() -> Self {
        Pawn { _state: Box::new(Self::ALL_STATES.into_iter().cycle()) }
    }

    fn tick(&mut self, steps: usize) -> u8 {
        (0..steps - 1).for_each(|_| {self._state.next();});
        self._state.next().unwrap()
    }
}

impl Clone for Pawn {

    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Self { _state: Box::new(*self._state.as_ref().clone()) }
    }
}
```

The constructor and the `tick` method work as they should. But I'd like to implement `Clone` for this struct as well. This is where I get lost:

```
the size for values of type `dyn Iterator<Item = u8>` cannot be known at compilation time
the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `dyn Iterator<Item = u8>`
```

It seems that I cannot make a new `Box` out of something that is not known at compile time, due to the dynamic dispatch. I know this will always be an iterator pointing to a `u8`, but I don't know how to tell the compiler.

Comment: If you know it will always be an iterator pointing to a `u8`, why is `_state` not a `Iterator<Item = u8>`?

Comment: Removing the Box doesn't make the problem go away. Now my entire Pawn struct is "size unknown" to the compiler. The box makes the Pawn struct itself sized. If you have a suggestion without Box it's also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know the actual type of `_state` and it is Sized, you can do away with all the trait objects and just define it directly.

```rust
struct Pawn {
    _state: std::iter::Cycle<std::array::IntoIter<u8, 10>>
}

impl Pawn {
    fn new() -> Self {
        // as before, but remove Box::new
    }
}

impl Clone for Pawn {

    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Self { _state: self._state.clone() }
    }
}
```

N.B. that if you did not know the exact type of `_state`, only that it was an iterator that produced `u8`s, you could still define clone if you parameterize its type in Pawn. Consider:

```rust
struct Pawn<S>
where
    S: Iterator<Item = u8>,
{
    _state: S,
}

impl Pawn<std::iter::Cycle<std::array::IntoIter<u8, 10>>> {
    const ALL_STATES: [u8; 10] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

    fn new() -> Self {
        Pawn {
            _state: Self::ALL_STATES.into_iter().cycle(),
        }
    }

    fn tick(&mut self, steps: usize) -> u8 {
        (0..steps - 1).for_each(|_| {
            self._state.next();
        });
        self._state.next().unwrap()
    }
}

// Note the extra trait bound here! S must also be clone
impl<S> Clone for Pawn<S>
where
    S: Iterator<Item = u8> + Clone,
{
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Self {
            _state: self._state.clone(),
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you simplified this a lot for this question, but if this is roughly your use case, it strikes me as a little over-engineered. Maybe you could consider a simpler design, something like

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct SimplePawn {
    state: u8,
}

impl SimplePawn {
    const STATES: usize = 10;

    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            state: 1,
        }
    }

    fn tick(&mut self, steps: usize) -> u8 {
        let mut state = self.state as usize - 1;
        state = (state + steps - 1) % Self::STATES + 1;
        let state = state as u8;
        self.state = state + 1; 
        state
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_equivalent() {
    // Where `Pawn` is the type that @AdamSmith suggested
    let mut pawn = Pawn::new();
    let mut simple_pawn = SimplePawn::new();
    
    for ticks in 1..1000 {
        assert_eq!(pawn.tick(ticks), simple_pawn.tick(ticks));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the better answer for this particular problem, but for circular states in general the above design is suitable. You've got my upvote :p

Comment: Sure, that's fair enough :)